# How to make use of Transient API as cookie

Tags: cookies, transient

I want to use Transient API as cookie, but I want to know if it is the best practice,and how to make transient be unique or per user. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In almost all circumstances, a cookie would be preferable to a transient. WP has a really bad habit of not cleaning up transients properly, so unless your code cleans up after itself (Kills useless transients) they will just sit forever in your DB. Even transients that are set to expire sometimes don't.

In terms of uniqueness, you'd generate a transient like so:

```
set_transient( $transient_name, $data_to_store, $expiration_time_in_seconds);
```

so to create a transient that would be user-specific would be something like:

```
$transient_name = 'name_this_whatever' . $user_id;
$expiration_time_in_seconds =  60*60*12;
set_transient( $transient_name, $data_to_store, $expiration_time_in_seconds);
```

Then later on, to retrieve the same field you'd just do:

```
$transient_name = 'name_this_whatever' . $user_id;
get_transient( $transient_name );
```

You might want to take a look at this SO discussion [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45065/when-should-i-be-using-the-transients-api?rq=1"") for a discussion about when transients may be best utilized.