# Single query for multiple categories

Tags: wp-query, categories

I want for my homepage to show 'x' latest posts from certain categories. The number of the posts returned depends on category. Either 10 or 15 posts/category.
I want to use a single query to DB to ease the server load (returned posts will be approx 70).
I'm thinking about a single `WP_Query`, selecting the category slugs and the max. no of `posts_per_page`. And then in the Loop I'll filter the results based on category name and limit by post counts. All post types are the default `post`.
Am i on the right path here or is there a better approach?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to return 10/15 posts from each category?

Comment: OK, so basically you're afraid of performance hit caused by multiple queries, so you want to select all posts and then loop through them? And what it there will be 200 posts per category?

Comment: @JackJohansson Yes that's the idea. The recent ones.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Maybe I didn't described it correctly. I don't want to select all posts. Just the last 15 of each category, but with a single or as few queries as possible.

Comment: You can't do that with a single `WP_Query()`. You can directly query posts using `SELECT TOP` SQL query, but that requires skill in writing and handling SQL queries.

Comment: @JackJohansson So i'll have to have one WP_Query() for each of my cat's. Is there something you'd suggest for a heavy-traffic page to not load my server's resources? What is the best approach in these scenarios?

Comment: Set a transient to cache the queries.  This will prevent the queries firing on each page load:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/271213/use-transient-api-to-cache-queries-for-all-posts-in-all-categories

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a website that has a high traffic, querying posts on each load will not be efficient. You should instead cache the data. Now, I'm not talking about a plugin that caches the pages, I'm talking about caching your query.

You can run 10 queries and fetch 10 post IDs from each category, and then form an array of post IDs and store them in the database, using a [transient](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API). This way, you can fetch the transient data and directly run a loop and output the post data.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I'll try the caching option.